# Memcached set() fails: WRITE FAILURE

Tags: php, memcached

So Memcached fails to write certain keys, getResultMessage() says `WRITE FAILURE`
I'm using this in setup:

```
$this->mmcache = new Memcached();
$this->mmcache->addServer('localhost',11211, 100);
$this->mmcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);
$this->mmcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_SERIALIZER, Memcached::SERIALIZER_IGBINARY);
$this->mmcache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION, false);
```

Some keys work every time, some fail everytime. I even tried base64 encoding the keys but they fail anyway, even simple function like

```
for($i=1;$i<100;$i++) {
  $this->mmcache->set('testkey'.$i,$i*100,600);
}
```

returns `WRITE FAILURE` every time.

Disabling the binary protocol just changes the error to `HOSTNAME LOOKUP FAILURE` but like 50% of keys still work and I just can't figure out which will and which won't work.

Sorry I was asking wrong question before.

---

*original question:* Memcache in v1.4.4 returning NULL
I'm storing and reading large quantities of data in memcache from php. I'm using regular connect to memcache server which runs on localhost. I'm using Memcache 1.4.4

But from 50-60 keys that I'm reading from memcache in one script run, more than 50% come back as `null`. According to php.net, `Memcache::get()` should return false when key doesn't exist or expired. So why would it return "null" ?

This happens even for keys that I just wrote to memcache. I cache something for 24 hours and in a minute I'm getting "null" instead. Memcache is not even 50% full so there's no reason for keys to be purged and even if they were, they should come back as false and not null.

Has anybody else encountered this problem ?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: you've double/triple checked that the data you add() isn't simply null?

Comment: yeah, absolutely, debuging all details on each step, some keys return values some nulls.

Comment: Doesn't memcache have an error log? It should contain more detailed information on what goes wrong.

Comment: Hi! Did you get any hold on why it occurred?

Comment: This sound similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920132/php-memcache-returns-false-with-increase-in-number-of-keys

Answer (score 3):

I had [the same problem](http://www.develophp.org/2012/02/php-memcached-extension-write-failures/) today.

It turns out you need to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Really annoying.

Comment: This worked for me. My php Memcached class used to work with "localhost". Was there a regression in a newer version?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds almost as if you're hitting the memory limit on Memcached. What kinds of things are you writing? How big are they?

If you Memcached server is full or almost full, I might even expect this to happen.

On the other hand, double check that you don't have a rate-limiting firewall installed. Perhaps it sees you banging away at your Memcached box and is freaking out.

Lastly, make sure that you're closing your Memcached connection when you're done with it. If you leave too many open, things get ugly.